# How prove this inequality $3a^3b+3ab^3+18a^2b+18ab^2+12a^3+12b^3+40a^2+40b^2+64ab\ge 0$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b\in[-1,1]$,

then prove or disprove:

> $$f(a,b)=3a^3b+3ab^3+18a^2b+18ab^2+12a^3+12b^3+40a^2+40b^2+64ab\ge 0$$

**My try:** Since
\begin{align*}
f(a,b)&=3a^3b+3ab^3+18a^2b+18ab^2+12a^3+12b^3+40a^2+40b^2+64ab\\
&=3ab(a^2+b^2)+18ab(a+b)+12(a^3+b^3)+40(a^2+b^2)+64ab
\end{align*}
if
$ab\ge 0$

then 
\begin{align*}&f(a,b)\ge 9ab(a^2+b^2)+18ab(a+b)+12(a^3+b^3)+40(a^2+b^2)+52ab\\
&=9ab(a^2+b^2)+18ab(a+b)+12(a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab)+40(a^2+b^2)+52ab\\
&=9ab(a^2+b^2)+6(a+b)(2a^2+2b^2+ab)+40(a^2+b^2)+52ab\\
&\ge0
\end{align*}

but for the other case, $ab\le 0$, I can't proceed.

This problem is a follow up from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624846/how-prove-this-inequality-fracab3-fracbc3-fraccd3-fracda?rq=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for $ab<0$, WLOG,let $a>0,-c=b<0 \to 1 \ge c>0$ so the inequality becomes:

$-3a^3c-3ac^3-18a^2c+18ac^2+12a^3-12c^3+40a^2+40c^2-64ac\ge 0$

$12c^2 \ge 12c^3,3ac^3 \ge 3ac^3,9ac^2+9a^3 \ge 18a^2c,3a^3 \ge 3a^3c,40a^2+28c^2\ge 64ac $

Comment: I've heard of WLOG, but WOLG?

Comment: Nice. For completeness' sake I will include it in my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/627147/71936) to the linked question where the problem originated, if you don't mind :)

Comment: @ElThor,my pleasure :)

Comment: @ByronSchmuland, thanks, correct it.