# SOS: Proof of the AM-GM inequality

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

["A basic strategy in tackling inequalities of few variables is to write things into sum of squares..."](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/432615/316749) is a quote from an answer, intended as commenting the post entitled "Can this inequality proof be demystified?".

I'd like to know what the **S**um **O**f **S**quares strategy yields for the AM-GM inequality with $\,n$ variables.
In the low-dimensional cases $\,n=2,3,4\,$ one has
\begin{align*}
a^2+b^2-2ab &\;=\;(a-b)^2\;\geqslant\;0\,, \\[2ex]
a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc &\;=\;(a+b+c)\cdot\underbrace{\frac 12\left((a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\right)}_{a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca}\;\geqslant\;0\,,\\[2ex]
a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4-4abcd &\;=\;\left(a^2-b^2\right)^2
+\left(c^2-d^2\right)^2 + 2(ab-cd)^2\;\geqslant\;0\,,
\end{align*}
and for $\,n=5\,$ cf this [math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2417264/316749).

Now fix some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $\,a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n\geqslant 0$, and consider
$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^n\, -\, n\prod_{k=1}^n a_k\tag{AM-GM}$$
which, I'm pretty convinced, can be expressed involving Sums Of Squares and then recognised to be non-negative.

- *But how does such an expression look like?*
- *Can it be derived in a (a sort of) uniform procedure?*

There's the post [Proofs of AM-GM inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/691807/316749) (tagged as 'big-list') with 14 answers currently, but none of them would answer this question.

I've considered to add the 'computer-algebra-systems' tag.

---

**Added in edit**
Pedro Tamaroff introduced the central keyword *Certificate of positivity* in his comment which, amongst further insights, led me to rediscover the above $n=4$ expression.

$\exists$ recommended readings:
(1) [*An algorithm for sums of squares of real polynomials*](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~vicki/pub/sos.pdf), J. Pure & Appl. Alg. 127 (1998), pp 99–104, is a nice paper by *Victoria Powers* and *Thorsten Wörmann*
(2) [*Computing sum of squares decompositions with rational coefficients*](http://www.mit.edu/~parrilo/pubs/files/PeyrlParrilo-ComputingSumOfSquaresDecompositionsWithRationalCoefficients.pdf)
by *Helfried Peyrl* and *Pablo A. Parrilo*, Theor. Comp. Sci. 409 (2008), pp 269-281

Comment: The cases $n=2$ and $n=3$ look pretty different to me. It would be easier to extrapolate a guess with more examples.

Comment: Maybe you could follow the Cauchy induction proof to get an expression for $n=2^k$ and then in general?

Comment: Do you have any specific reason for being convinced?  Consider the case $n=5$.  A sum of squares (of homogeneous terms) will give even powers only and hence you won't get terms in $a^5$.  You would have to take out a linear factor first as you have done for $n=3$.  Unfortunately, the expression with $n=5$ doesn't have any linear factors, at any rate not according to Maple.  So, sorry to sound negative - and maybe someone else can think of some smart idea that I've missed - but it seems to me that this method is unlikely to work.

Comment: The keyword here is 'positivity certificate', which you can probably google and read about. I found these [slides](https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~goddard/MINI/2011/Powers.pdf) when doing so.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff
Your comment is a smash hit: It pathed me the way to a short certificate in the 4-variable case; cf the edit.

Comment: @Hanno I'm glad to be helpful. ;)

Comment: @David It does not come as a surprise to me that the $n=5$ expression hasn't any linear factors, or equivalently, that it cannot be written as a product (which is special to the  $n=3$ case).
I'd rather expect that a linear combination of squares exists with coefficients whose positivity is obvious, cf. the coefficient $\frac 12(x+y+z)$ in the $n=3$ case, or the involved expression for  $n=5$ in M. Rozenberg's answer below.
 
My hope is $\ddot\smile$ that coefficients can be found which are homogeneous of degree 1. Would Maple be able to detect corresponding decompositions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we can write $x_1^n+x_2^n+...+x_n^n-nx_1x_2...x_n$ in the SOS form, but I think it's very ugly and it's not useful for big $n$.

We can make the following.

For $n=3$:
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=\sum_{cyc}\left(a^3-\frac{1}{2}a^2b-\frac{1}{2}a^2c\right)+\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{2}a^2b+\frac{1}{2}a^2c-abc\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(a+b)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}c(a-b)^2=\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2.$$

For $n=4$:
$$a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4-4abcd=\sum_{cyc}\left(a^4-\frac{1}{3}(a^3b+a^3c+a^3d)\right)+$$
$$+\frac{1}{6}\sum_{sym}(a^3b-a^2b^2)+\frac{1}{6}\sum_{sym}(a^2b^2-a^2bc)+\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}(a^2bc+a^2cd+a^2bd-3abcd)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\left(\sum_{sym}(a^4-a^3b)+\sum_{sym}(a^3b-a^2b^2)+\sum_{sym}(a^2b^2-a^2bc)+\sum_{sym}(a^2bc-abcd)\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{12}\left(\sum_{sym}(a^4-a^3b-ab^3+b^4)+\sum_{sym}(a^3b-2a^2b^2+ab^3)+\sum_{sym}(c^2a^2-2c^2ab+c^2b^2)+\sum_{sym}(a^2cd-2abcd+b^2cd)\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{12}\sum_{sym}(a-b)^2(a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+cd)=$$
$$=\tfrac{(a-b)^2(2(a+b)^2+(c+d)^2)+(a-c)^2(2(a+c)^2+(b+d)^2)+(a-d)^2(2(a+d)^2+(b+c)^2)}{6}+$$
$$+\tfrac{(b-c)^2(2(b+c)^2+(a+d)^2)+(b-d)^2(2(b+d)^2+(a+c)^2)+(c-d)^2(2(c+d)^2+(a+b)^2)}{6}.$$
Here $$\sum\limits_{sym}a=6(a+b+c+d)$$ $$\sum\limits_{sym}a^2b^2=4(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2d^2+c^2d^2),...$$
For $n=5$: 
$$a^5+b^5+c^5+d^5+e^5-5abcde=\frac{1}{24}\sum_{sym}(a^5-abcde)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{24}\left(\sum_{sym}(a^5-a^4b)+\sum_{sym}(a^4b-a^3b^2)+\sum_{sym}(a^3b^2-a^3bc)\right)+$$
$$+\frac{1}{24}\left(\sum_{cyc}(a^3bc-a^2b^2c)+\sum_{sym}(a^2b^2c-a^2bcd)+\sum_{sym}(a^2bcd-abcde)\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{48}\left(\sum_{sym}(a^5-a^4b-ab^4+b^5)+\sum_{sym}(a^4b-a^3b^2-a^2b^3+ab^4)+\sum_{sym}(c^3a^2-2c^3ab+c^3b^2)\right)+$$
$$+\frac{1}{48}\left(\sum_{cyc}(a^3bc-2a^2b^2c+b^3ac)+\sum_{sym}(a^2c^2d-2c^2abd+b^2c^2d)+\sum_{sym}(a^2cde-2abcde+b^2cde)\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{48}\sum_{sym}(a-b)^2(a^3+2a^2b+2ab^2+b^3+c^3+abc+c^2d+cde).$$
The rest is the same.

Comment: Could you explain your general ansatz, your systematics in decomposing the (AM-GM) expression (thus fleshing out the formulae)?

Comment: Even not grasping it in full, you convinced me that the transformation into an SOS expression is always possible, in principle $\,\Rightarrow$ *Upvote & thanks for that!* The resulting expressions rapidly getting monstrous doesn't come as a surprise, SOS then acqires its well-known standard meaning **;-)**